# Posting a comment on a Question

Tags: support, comments

I just noticed that you cannot add a comment to someone's question, for example, to ask for clarification.  In my case, I wanted to ask the poster if the answer had sufficiently covered their question, and if so to please mark the question as answered.  However, you can't add a comment to someone's initial question, only post an answer or comment on an answer.  This capability is present on at least [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a rep requirement ([50](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment)) for commenting everywhere (the exception being when it is your own question or answer).  You have above 50 rep on Tex.  I'm afraid there's not any flexibility in this requirement.

You should be able to leave a comment on your own answer and `@` the OP.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I think it accumulated so quickly on tex.stackexchange that I was sort of oblivious to it.

Comment: @JM It's one of those double-edged swords, it's a necessary deterrent against junk comments, but it's an inconvenience when you're starting out.  You'll get to 50 in no time.